# Sorting NSTableColumn with NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a NSArrayController bound to an NSTableView so the table column like the following:

```
NSTableView bindings:
Content -> ArrayController.arrangedObjects
SelectionIndexs -> ArrayController.arrangedObjects
SortDescriptors -> ArrayController.sortDescriptors

NSTableColumn bindings:
Value -> ArrayController.arrangedObjects.description
```

When I try and sort it using the column header it just crashes with something like

```
error setting value for key path sortDescriptors of object NSArrayController
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me suggest you a simple way to do this -

```
NSTableColumn bindings:

Value -> 

Bind to: ArrayController

Controller Key : arrangedObjects

Model Key Path : keyPath (such as name)
```

If you are new to using bindings with table view, this article will be of great help to you-

**EDIT:** Project relocated to Github. (No more explanation - code only)

[NSTableView, NSArrayController and More Bindings](https://github.com/alexjohnj/simplecode-sample-source/tree/master/2011/07/NSTableViews,%20NSArrayControllers%20and%20More%20Bindings)

Comment: The above answer will not sort

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with the exact same problem today.

It seems that binding the content and selectionIndexes of the tableView to the array controller `IB > inspector window > select your tableView > bindings tab`, disables the sorting by clicking on the table header. This makes sense, because the table view now shows you the exact contents (and ordering) of the array controller.

I unchecked these bindings in the IB, also removed any sort keys from the table columns `IB > inspector window > select your NSTableColumn > attributes pane`. Select the checkbox `Creates Sort Descriptor` in the table column's binding tab.  No sortDescriptor is needed on the table, although I think binding the table's sortDescriptor to `Shared User Defaults Controller` saves the ordering when you quit your application.

If you need to sort your table, put a sortDescriptor on the array controller, maybe in the `awakeFromNib`.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"propertyOfYourObject" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)]]];
}
```

This does not interfere with clicking the table column headers.

I couldn't get a sortDescriptor on the array controller to work with bindings.

Comment: you should be able to get the sortDescriptor to work with bindings if you, as you mention, remove the content binding from the NSTableView which is what disables automatic sort descriptors on the columns.

I bound my NSTableColumns programatically to the arraycontroller and specified the "Create Sort Descriptor" binding option like so:

     
    [column bind:@"value" toObject:self.arrayController withKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"arrangedObjects.%@",c.key] options:@{NSCreatesSortDescriptorBindingOption : @(YES)}];

Answer (score 2):

I see several issues in your binding attempt.

1. One doesn't usually need to bind the `NSTableView` at all. Binding the values of specific `NSTableColumn`s to the NSArrayController is enough.
2. You try to bind something against a **.description** property. Please remember - "**description**" is like a "reserved word" in Obj-C. Any NSObject should present itself as `NSString` in its "description" method. This is what is called when you `po <object>` in the debugger, or pass an `NSObject` to NSLog via "%@". So... probably you'd want to rename your property to something else.
3. You do NOT need to bind the sort descriptors of the `NSArrayController` or the `NSTableView` or the `NSTableColumn` at all. As it happens, when you bind an `NSTableColumn`'s value to the `NSArrayController`'s `arrangedObjects`, the `NSTableColumn` (actually the `NSColumnHeader`) object knows to set the `NSArrayController`'s `sortDescriptor` to the same path as the one you specified for the column's value binding - as you click on the column header. In other words - sorting by clicking on column headers comes free, if you just bind your column's value to the NSArrayController's arrangedObjects.

Documentation on table binding is bad and frustrating. There are several different schemes for working with a Table, and debugging binding problems is a real nightmare. However, there are plenty essays and tutorials on the net for this.

Hope this helps.